# Is MSN chat encrypted or not? If not how can I make it encrypted?

Tags: encryption, chat, pidgin

How can I force pidgin to use only encrypted connections when using MSN chat? I'm on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't encrypted, you can use the [off-the-record plugin](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/) that's available as a [third-party plugin](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins#SecurityandPrivacy) for Pidgin. FYI Off the record is available for Gaim, Adium and also as a compiled binary for Pidgin on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if MSN is encrypted but if you can use and get your buddies to use [the Off the Record](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/) plugin your communications will be encrypted and also not understandable to potential intercepting parties.